# Data.Map with functions as values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, option-type

I'm a Haskell newbie trying to understand how to work with the `Data.Map` structure, lazy evaluation, and the `Maybe` type.

In Python I can define a dictionary structure whose values are functions. Given a key I can then use the corresponding function:

```python
d = {"+": lambda x,y: x+y}

def f(key, v1, v2):
    if key in d:
        return d[key](v1, v2)
    else:
        return 0
```

I've tried to do a similar thing in Haskell but it does not compile.

```
d = Map.fromList [('+', (+))]

f :: Char -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
f key v1 v2 =
    if k == Nothing
        then 0
        else f v1 v2
    where
        k = Map.lookup key d
        (Just f) = k
```

This doesn't compile and returns an error like

```
No instance for (Eq (Integer -> Integer -> Integer))
```

I believe it's because `Map.lookup '+' d` only returns an instance of `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)` not `(Just (+))` or `Nothing`. And I assume this has to do with lazy evaluation.

Is there a Haskell-like way to do this kind of thing? Am I working with the Maybe type incorrectly? Can I force evaluation of the lookup?

This came up because I was trying to implement a reverse polish calculator in Haskell. I used the dictionary to organize the possible functions I could be using. I found a nice solution (https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm#Haskell) without a dictionary but now I just want to understand how to properly access values in a Haskell `Data.Map`.

Comment: Note that, even if that worked, it is considered non idiomatic in Haskell. In many imperative programming languages it is somehow common to find methods like `obj.getX()` which will throw an exception unless one checks `obj.hasX()` beforehand. This is frowned upon in Haskell, since it is easy to forget the check: in your code, if you used `f` without checking `k == Nothing` first, you would crash the program. Fortunately, pattern matching provides a better way to solve it: in a `case` we are prodded to consider all the constructors, and act accordingly -- this is always safe.

Comment: I'd also recommend to read about [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is this expression: `k == Nothing`

It requires `k` to support equality testing. The type of `k` is `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`. `Maybe T` supports equality testing if `T` does, but `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` doesn't: You can't compare functions for equality. So the whole expression doesn't typecheck.

I don't know what you mean by "*an instance of `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`*": Classes have instances (which are types), but `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)` is not a class, it's an ordinary type. The class in question is `Eq` (which provides the `==` method). The issue is that function types don't have an `Eq` instance. This has nothing to do with lazy evaluation, either.

---

The solution is to just use pattern matching instead:

```
f key v1 v2 =
    case Map.lookup key d of
        Nothing -> 0
        Just f  -> f v1 v2
        -- but consider naming 'f' something else;
        -- the surrounding function is already called 'f'
```

Alternatively you can use one of the `Maybe` helper functions:

```
f key v1 v2 =
    maybe 0 (\f -> f v1 v2) (Map.lookup key d)
```

Or even:

```
f key v1 v2 =
    fromMaybe (\_ _ -> 0) (Map.lookup key d) v1 v2
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. Thanks for also explaining why this has nothing to do with lazy evaluation. And point taken on my double use of the variable `f`!

Comment: @Ben: I'd add that more generally, things like equality comparisons are eschewed in Haskell. [Boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/) is the keyword: you rely on expressions of unspecific types like `Bool` to decide how more specific types like `Maybe (Int -> Int -> Int)`. The preferred solution is to work _only_ with the specific, meaningful types; this prevents a lot of bugs. Pattern matching is great in this regard.

Comment: "an instance of `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`" means a value whose types is `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`.

Comment: @immibis That sentence continues "*not `(Just (+))` or `Nothing`*", but those are values of type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`. That makes no sense.

Comment: @melpomene Indeed, the thing following it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the function `(== Nothing)` as type `(Eq a) => Maybe a -> Bool`, in your case, functions not being a member of the `Eq` typeclass, this doesn't compile.

However you can use the `isNothing` function from `Data.Maybe`, or you can define it yourself like this:

```
isNothing :: Maybe a -> Bool
isNothing Nothing = True
isNothing (Just _) = False
```

Because you are pattern-matching on the constructor and therefore not using `(==)`, you don't need `a` to be an instance of `Eq`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using `k` of type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)` in a comparison expression. Haskell does not know how to compare two functions.

A solution is to 'unpack' the return of lookup.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map                                                                 

d = Map.fromList [('+', (+))]                                                                    

f :: Char -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer                                                       
f key v1 v2 =                                                                                    
  case Map.lookup key d of                                                                       
    Nothing -> 0                                                                                 
    Just f -> f v1 v2
```

.

```
λ> f '-' 1 2                                                                                     
0                                                                                                
λ> f '+' 1 2                                                                                     
3                                                                                                
λ>
```